# Eclipse - Shift Left/Right One Space

Tags: eclipse

On an old computer using Eclipse Indigo I had key bindings set up that let me shift selected text one space left and one space right (vs. a tab / 4 spaces at a time).  I've since migrated to a new computer and installed Eclipse Juno.  The Shift Left and Shift Right key bindings are there, but they move my text 4 spaces at a time.  Can I change this to use a single space instead, while maintaining a 4-space TAB key?